# Interface. Join areas is not working properly

Tags: interface

I made a mess with areas trying to merge them into 2. Is there a way to remove areas without aiming at the corner and then dragging them with LMB? [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just <kbd>right click</kbd> on the border and select *Join Areas*.
Then you can choose which way to merge them.

[image]